# two-person continuous game

Tags: game-theory

Can anyone help me solve this question? Thanks in advance!
In a two-person continuous game the strategies are between 0 and 1, and the two payoff functions are `f1 = x+y-(x+y)^2` and `f2 = xy - y^2 + 2x`.
Find the equilibrium.

Comment: Hi Jaden! Please edit to show your effort. What have you tried? Also, can you please specify which variable is which player's strategy?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming x is for player 1 and y is for player 2, we can proceed as

$\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x}=1-2(x+y)=0 \Rightarrow x+y=\frac{1}{2}$

$\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial y}=x-2y=0$

On solving, $x=\frac{1}{3}$ and  $y=\frac{1}{6}$

So, the Nash equilibrium is ($\frac{1}{3}$,$\frac{1}{6}$)